# HTTPS website redirects to HTTP

Tags: ssl, https

I bought an SSL certificate from GoDaddy, installed it on my EC2 instance and when I visit the IP of the instance directly with https the certificate shows up installed fine (though it warns me that something may be wrong because I'm not visiting it from the right domain name.)

But when I went to GoDaddy and changed my A record to point to my instance's IP address, when I go to the HTTPS site it forwards me to HTTP - i.e. the SSL certificate doesn't show up anymore.

What can I do about this? If you need more specifics I would be glad to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably configured the SSL site that is associated with the domain name to redirect back to the HTTP site, while the IP address is a different vhost.  Check your per-vhost access logs to see which one gets the log entries for each request, and then compare/contrast/examine/fix the config entries as required to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm so sorry to sound like an idiot but I honestly lost you after you said that you think my the SSL redirects back to the HTTP site. I'm pretty new to this site. Is there any tutorial or articles I should read that can give me more specifics on how to do something like check the per-vhost access log (not sure what that is) and figure out what's going on. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you're pretty far out of your comfort zone.  Perhaps it might be best to drop into chat (we all hang out in "The Comms Room" and talk the problem through with People Who Know.  Diagnosing your problem via comments is unlikely to end well.

Comment: Ok :) thanks I think I figured it out (it was a DNS issue)